# Eclipse programmatically import TeamProjectSet

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I have a TeamProjectSet file and now I want to import it programmatically.

The projects are in an SCM and so I also need to pass the requiered username and password. This should be done without any user interaction.

Is this possible to do and if it is possible how I can achieve this?